# How to build an PHP array from mysql query

Tags: list

I have a php code that needs an array in order to work. example:

```
$cities = array( array('city'=>'New York', country=>'US', zip=>'10001'),
array('city'=>'Los Angeles', country =>'US', zip=>'90001'),
array('city'=>'Chicago', country =>'US', zip=>'60601'),
array('city'=>'Houston', country =>'US', zip=>'77001'),
);
```

I need to recreate this array with a mysql query. I wrote that code:

```
<?php
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","xxx","xxxx") or die(mysql_error());
    $var_db= 'xxx';
    mysql_select_db($var_db,$connection) or die(mysql_error());
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT city,country,zip FROM villes_france") or die(mysql_error());

$Cities = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $Cities[0] = array($row['city'], $row['country'], $row['zip']);
    }
?>
```

It does not work at all. first of all, echo $Cities returns Array on the webpage. Finally, my php code using the mysql instead of the manual array does not work either. Could you please help me?

thanks in advance,
Regards,

Comment: Use PDO and its `fetchAll()`. The mysql extension is deprecated anyway.

Comment: yep PDO is indeed better. thanks!